# Google Regex Exclusion

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regex-group

Have been looking into this without success. Have a long list of strings like so:

COLOR-12345_101.tif

RED-12345_101_av1.tif

OBJ-23456_456_av1.tif

RED_ESCAPADE.tif

SKYSCAPE_BLUE.tif

TWIST_OF_BLUE.tif

Trying to use Google RegexExtract to remove file extensions and "_av1" when present.

I've tried using the expression: "^[\w-]*[^_av1.]" which I understand to be 
^ at the beginning
[\w-]* group of word characters or "-" of any len
[^av1.] subtract group "av1."

Problem is this takes the last character if it's a "1":

PROD-12345_101_av1.tif. becomes PROD-12345_10

I've tried using "?!" but Google seems to struggle with this. I simply want a literal string to be rejected and can only manage a group so far.

Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search for

```
(?:_av1)?(?:\.[^.]+)$
```

which looks for an optional `_av1` followed by a `.` and then some number of non-`.` characters up to the end of the string, and replace that (using `REGEXREPLACE`) with an empty string.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/eP8mRt/1)

Comment: I think OP needs to use `REGEXREPLACE` instead of extraction. So without optional capture groups he can use `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(_av1)?\.[^.]+$","")` yielding results he is after. Good pattern, Regex on GS isn't always as straightforward unfortunately =)

Comment: @JvdV good point, I've made that explicit in the answer. Does GS not support non-capturing groups?

Comment: It does, as your pattern seemed to work. As a matter of fact I simply tried to imply it was possible without them. I tried to make a comment stating RE2 regular expressions on GS can sometimes be a $@&* since it's [not supporting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=nl) quite a bit of very regular patterns we use almost daily. Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @JvdV no worries; I was pretty sure it did but wanted to be certain (so that I could remove them if required). I agree with you about not needing the second one, generally though any groups which aren't required in the output should be non-capturing for performance.

Comment: That I did not know =). Thanks.

Comment: @Nick, tried the first example and this works perfectly- had not thought of finding and removing the end rather than keeping the beginning string. To be sure I follow the Regex: "(?:_av1)?" looks for one or no occurrences of "_av1" but does not capture that group; the second part I'm a bit fuzzy, "(?:\.[^.]+)$" looks for a literal "." but does not match it, then excludes one or more characters anchored to the end of the string?

Comment: @Ian, have a look at the included link in the answer. At the top there is a nice step-by-step explaination of the pattern= )

Comment: @Ian there's no need to capture groups as they are going to be replaced with an empty string. The first group as you say looks for 0 or 1 occurrences of `_av1`. The second looks for a literal `.`, followed by one of more non-`.` characters and end of string. That ensures that the group matches the actual extension of the file and doesn't give a false match against a `.` in the middle of a file name such as `abc.def.ghi`. I hope this helps. If you look at the demo and remove the `?:` from  the groups, you can see what they match in each test string.